# Rotate Polygon to be Parallel with the X Axis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

By default, PostGIS calculates the Envelope or Extent of a polygon based on the bounding box of the polygon ((MINX, MINY), (MINX, MAXY), (MAXX, MAXY), (MAXX, MINY), (MINX, MINY)).

This gives a result like so:

[image]

However, I'm looking for a result more like this:

[image]

As far as I know, the best algorithm that I can come up with is:

1. Determine angle `a` to rotate the polygon `X` to be parallel with the x-axis
2. Rotate `X` `a` degrees, calculate the envelope `Y` of rotated polygon `X`
3. Rotate `Y` `-a` degrees

How could you calculate step #1 in PostGIS?

Comment: Your algorithm description is not clear. What do you mean by "polygon `X`" and "envelope `Y`"? Also, the goals are not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but minumum bounding rectangle function may still be missing from PostGIS
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2012-June/034419.html

Meanwhile you can use OpenJUMP which can read and write data from PostGIS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's missing, but [an enhancement ticket is in place](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3176)